# CKAN: Get user object or id when a context object is not available in extension

Tags: authentication, ckan

When writing a CKAN extension, I can create a custom GET-able method, which automatically receives the context.

e.g.

```
@side_effect_free
def custom_method(context, data_dict):
    # Do something with the context and/or data_dict
```

The context argument above, which is basically injected by CKAN, contains, among other things, the user object which can be used to identify the user.

In other cases, like for example in a template helper, how can I get access to the user information? Ideally, I would like to have a context object just as above, so that I can call for example package_search and the rest of the actions provided in the toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when calling actions, skipping the context variable will cause ckan to add it later inside the call, so there's no need to provide the context yourself. Also, if you want information on the user, the g variable from Flask has everything you need.